# numpys fancy indexing pattern

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I am trying to get my head around numpy's fancy indexing.
While trying to approach the following I am currently unable to solve the problem:

Given the following np.array t.

```
t = np.array([[6, 1, 8],
           [4, 3, 7],
           [9, 5, 2]])
```

I want to achieve the following pattern using fancy indexing

```
array([[8, 1, 8],
       [1, 8, 1],
       [8, 1, 8]])
```

With my closest approach getting to

```
array([[8, 1, 8],
       [8, 1, 8],
       [8, 1, 8]])
```

Using `t[:,[2,1,2]][[0,0,0]]`

how to tackle such problems?

Comment: What is "fancy indexing"? You mean Python's standard-since-forever list slicing syntax? Because if so, there's tons of explainers on the web about how to use that already. Including on SO, of course. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Comment: Thanks for pointing out.
In fancy indexing (in difference to list slicing) one passes arrays as indices.

Comment: Fancy indexing is definitely a python datascience term (albeit rarely used). Simple google search would've shown that though. No need for sass. There is a good read on it here: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.07-fancy-indexing.html @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: No sass, just good old genuine confusion about an unusual term I've never seen used despite having worked with numpy on more than several occasions.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, that link is for `numpy`, not base Python.  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing uses the name **advanced indexing**.  For lists there are only 2 options - slices and individual indices.

Answer (score 0):

I found two approaches which solve the problem.

1. Map the indices with the corresponding points to a 2d array of row and column coordinates.

   ```
   row = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])
   col = np.array([[2,1,2],[1,2,1],[2,1,2]])

   t[row,col]

   array([[8, 1, 8],
          [1, 8, 1],
          [8, 1, 8]])
   ```

which is the same as using

```
t[  [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]  ,  [[2,1,2],[1,2,1],[2,1,2]]  ]
```

2. Start by creating a 1d Array including only required numbers and then cast to a 2d array, allthough is approach triggers a Future Warning: *Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.*

   ```
     t[0,[1,2]] [[  [[1,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,1]]  ]]

     array([[8, 1, 8],
            [1, 8, 1],
            [8, 1, 8]])
   ```

Comment: Your first solution can also be reduced to `t[0, col]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [198]: t = np.array([[6, 1, 8],
     ...:            [4, 3, 7],
     ...:            [9, 5, 2]])
```

Looks like you want to take 2 elements, and repeat them.

```
In [199]: t[0,[2,1]]                 # select the elements
Out[199]: array([8, 1])
```

Then taking advantage of how `np.resize` "pads" a larger array:

```
In [200]: np.resize(_,(3,3))
Out[200]: 
array([[8, 1, 8],
       [1, 8, 1],
       [8, 1, 8]])
```

That's not a very general solution, but then I don't know how you'd imagine generalizing the problem

Another way to expand and reshape

```
In [217]: np.repeat(t[[[0]],[2,1]],5,0).ravel()[:9].reshape(3,3)
Out[217]: 
array([[8, 1, 8],
       [1, 8, 1],
       [8, 1, 8]])
```